# Maximum distance to station

Tags: code-golf

Looking at the following hackerrank problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flatland-space-stations

You are given a number n where cities can be at indices 0 to n-1 and also given an unsorted list of indices of cities where there are stations. The goal is to find the maximum distance from a city to a station. For example, for n=5 and the station list [0,4], the answer would be 2 since index 2 is 2 away from both 0 and 4 and all other stations at indices 0-4 are closer to one of 0 or 4.

---

I'm particularly interested in a short Python3 solution. The function body takes in the number n and a list c (like [0,4] in the example). After some revisions, I came up with the 69 character function body below:

```
c.sort();return max(t-s for s,t in zip([-c[0]]+c,c+[2*n-c[-1]-1]))//2
```

Curious about whether anyone can come up with a shorter body.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Could you clarify how you are counting size?  Your solution is not valid python on its own and doesn't fit any of our standard answer formats here. It is really important to know these parameters.

Comment: I think this should also explain the problem itself a little more.  Users should be able to understand the problem without having to go to some external site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Have clarified that I am looking for the shortest function body possible and have specified the inputs the function takes in. Have also explained the sample case further so that the problem is hopefully clearer.

Comment: You should maybe provide a standard function header that you want people to use. This will resolve issues around recursion and default arguments.

Comment: `2*n-c[-1]-1` can be golfed to `2*n+~c[-1]` as a start ([relevant tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144481/52210)). :) And based on the `//` I assume we're using Python 3 (or 3.8) here?

Comment: Is there any reason to limit this challenge to Python?

Comment: I have no problem with other solutions, you can post them if you want. I'm specifically interested in Python3 cause it's a language that I use every day and some of the languages used on this site are a bit esoteric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance solution:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 Bytes

```python
return max(min(abs(l-c)for l in s)for c in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYpBCsIwEADvfcUed2GFaLNI/Yp6iDXVQLstmwj6@mgFb85pGGZ5lfusbb3GAQIqZzo08OFULZaHKUzhiVNSDJeM46anYTYYISnkr/arWtBbRCWqiyUtGFD46NifiZpf2Tr3v3kWz63w3vNOuOtYWNapvgE)

Index solution (added after my first two comments):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```python
return max((min(abs(l-c)for l in s),c)for c in range(n))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYpBCsIwEADvfcUed2GF1GaR@pW2h1hTDbTbkkTQ10eLeHNuM8z2yvdVm3L1EzhUTnSu4ENfos@PqLC4J@ISFN0l4XwYaVojzBAUEvHXxt2i05tHJerqoWwxaEaHwp1hOxBVv1Ib879ZFsuN8MnyUbhtWVj2qbwB)

Edit: Switched back to Distance solution,
Thanks to Jonathan Allan for -1 Byte

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm questioning the validity of my results, the second test (on TIO) should be 100? I think I calculated the distance, not the index.

Comment: Fixed! Added 8 characters.

Comment: Excellent solution, I like your usage of the second list comprehension to avoid sorting and dividing by 2 and how you took advantage of tuples. To clarify, I was looking for a solution for maximum distance and I'm really impressed that you also found one for the index.

Comment: You can remove the space in `) for`.

Comment: The reference implementation does return the distance rather than the index, so the 52 byter should be good.

Comment: Yes, the title of this challenge says "maximum distance". I got 95 in your second TIO test as well (in my perl answer).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Ｉ⌈Ｅθ⌊↔⁻ηι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexIjO3NBdIF2gU6ij4ZuaBuY5Jxfk5pSWpGkCB0mKNDB2FTE0IsP7/P9pUJ9pAxyQ29r9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ        First input
  Ｅ         Map over implicit range
        ι   Current value
       η    Second input
     ↔⁻     Absolute difference
    ⌊       Minimum
 ⌈          Maximum
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

```perl
sub{max(map{$i=$_-1;min(map abs$i-$_,@_)}1..shift)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zdbdToMwFADge57iSBoD5GwBRlUgKPcad6NXuBCmoI3jZ7SLM4RnZ8Am2xvYXjRt2nPypWmbU6X1hnYkCzq@Wzd5stfypGoIC0g8s/ycFcMckjUnbEZiDGO9teZz/sUyobedD1I3JStrTWbf0EUUIxOdFQT3YK9QPp9lYmShOwIdqYBnn33yLST1mWijgzd4NyotSZR/PvN8A10q0Qle@BykDi4o3jpoU3RdpEiPZ/mPb0aR@/sDRW/k9g1d/quRAgkXiWBlwZGk@yp9F@mHHoQk9iXwkc9SBNckG5zhBNX9cbmqWSFg2ALpFiY8PIBafqvggWoYxvPyBZaPV@pliNqPhsTH0FNYMCV4K/rdreT3a8dTeGJceN6rYBvY/mh9xQB9FaFLURl0Bw)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```r
function(n,l)max(apply(abs(sapply(1:n-1,`-`,l)),2,min))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYxBCoMwEEX3PckMfCGxGcRCzxJTixDQUZoI9vRpSrcuunvw3v@vsoTDP2PKPq8@5ZDjqvcy7Tp@iRQz14LCts1vCo9E6Yf2po3F0Aw1YLRYojKfnZFgJAPHfDmz1pg/vIM4XAWdQyvoewikDsoH)

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 8 bytes

```
:q-|X<X>
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%3Aq-%7CX%3CX%3E&inputs=5%0A%5B0%3B4%5D&version=22.4.0)

**Explanation**

```
       % Implicitly grab the first input, N as an integer
:      % Create an array from 1...N
q      % Subtract one from each element to get a 0-based range: 0...N-1
-      % Implicitly grab the second input (a column vector) and subtract the
       % the two, broadcasting this out into a matrix of distances between 
       % all cities and stations where each city is a column and the distance
       % to each station is on each row
|      % Take the absolute value of the result
X<     % Compute the minimum value of each column (e.g. distance of each
       % city to closest station)
X>     % Compute the maximum value of these distances (furthest city 
       % from any station)
       % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ḶạṂ¥€Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//4bi24bqh4bmCwqXigqzhuYD///81/1swLCA0XQ)

**5 bytes** if you allow indexing from 1:

```
ạṂ¥€Ṁ
```

### Explanation

```
ḶạṂ¥€Ṁ   Main dyadic link
Ḷ        [0..n-1]
    €    Map
   ¥     (
 ạ         Absolute difference [from each station position]
  Ṃ        Minimum
   ¥     )
     Ṁ   Maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
FINαßM
```

Inputs in the order \$n,s\$

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzdPv3MbD833//zflijbQMYkFAA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6H@3CL9zGw/P9/1fq6MZ8z862lQn2kDHJDZWRyHa0MAAjWOiY2qiY2yqY26iY2SqY2mpY6pjGhsbCwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
F       # Loop `N` in the range [0, (implicit) input `n`):
 I      #  Push input-list `s`
  Nα    #  Get the absolute difference of each value in `s` with `N`
    ß   #  Pop and leave the minimum of the list
     M  #  Push a copy of the largest number on the stack to the top of the stack
        # (after the loop, the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ê├ô_ï-±╓\;]╙
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wqkdT5hzeEn94ve6hjY@mTo6xjn00deb//6YKBjomXIYGBnDaRMfURMfYVMfcRMfIVMfSUsdUxxQA)

Or alternatively:

```
rhêa*m-±mÄ╓╙
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/78o4/CqRK1c3UMbcw@3PJo6@dHUmf//myoY6JhwGRoYwGkTHVMTHWNTHXMTHSNTHUtLHVMdUwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ê         # Push all inputs as list (`n` and `s` are merged as single list)
 ├        # Extract the first item: pop and have list `s` and integer `n` separated on
          # the stack
  ô       # Loop `n` amount of times, using 6 characters as inner code-block:
   _      #  Duplicate list `s`
    ï     #  Push the 0-based loop index
     -    #  Subtract it from each value in list `s`
      ±   #  Take the absolute value of each
       ╓  #  Pop and push the minimum
        \ #  Swap so list `s` is at the top again for the next iteration
   ;      # Discard the remaining `s` after the loop
    ]     # Wrap all minima on the stack into a list
     ╙    # Pop and push the maximum
          # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
r         # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input `n`)
 h        # Get its length (without popping): `n`
  ê       # Push input-list `s`
   a      # Wrap the list into a list
    *     # Multiply it to the length, so we have a list of `n` amount of lists `s`
     m-   # Subtract the values in the two lists from one-another
          # (which required the lists to be of equal length)
       ±  # Take the absolute value of each
m         # Map over each inner list,
 Ä        # using 1 character as inner code-block:
  ╓       #  Pop and push the minimum
   ╙      # Pop and push the maximum
          # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÆVËaXÃÍÎÃÍ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=xlbLYVjDzc7DzQ&input=NQpbMCw0XQ)